# How does titan store vertex id (translate vertex id to HBase key column)?

Tags: hbase, titan

I'm using `titan` version 0.5.0 with `HBase`.
I've a region that doesn't split due to a vertex with a lot of edges and I would like to know what is the id of this vertex.
How can I translate the HBase key column to titan vertex id?

My HBase key column is `\x00\x8C\x1D\xB3\xBDZ<\x10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function used for converting `HBase` key column to `Titan` vertex id is `getKey` under the class `IDManager` (in titan-core).

Here is the code after taking it out. **It works for NormalVertex only**.

```
String hexKey = "008C1DB3BD5A3C10";
byte[] byteArr = BaseEncoding.base16().decode(hexKey);
StaticArrayBuffer buff = new StaticArrayBuffer(byteArr,0,hexKey.length());

// The code from titan with some simplifications
long partitionBits = 6;
long normalVertexOffset = 3l;
long TOTAL_BITS = Long.SIZE - 1;

long value = b.getLong(0);
long partitionOffset = Long.Size - partitionBits;
IDManager.VertexIDType type = IDManager.VertexIDType.NormalVertex;
long partition = partitionOffset < Long.SIZE ? value >>> partitionOffset : 0;
long USERVERTEX_PADDING_BITWIDTH = normalVertexOffset;
long count = ( value >>> USERVERTEX_PADDING_BITWIDTH & ((1l <<(partitionOffset - USERVERTEX_PADDING_BITWIDTH )) -1 );

long partitionIDBound = (1l << (partitionBits));
long id = (count << partitionBits) + partition;
if(type != null) id = type.addPadding(id);
System.out.println("Key is " + id);
```